# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to count the numbers of each character in a string

My code here:

```
def CharCount(string):
    mydict = {}
    for char in string:
        mydict[char] = mydict.get(char) + 1
    return '\n'.join(['%s,%s' % (c, n) for c, n in mydict.items()])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print CharCount("abcda")
```

On running above code I am getting below error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: `None` is what `dict.get(char)` returns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict.get(key)` returns `None` by default if `key` isn't in the dictionary. Provide a useful default value instead:

```
for char in string:
    mydict[char] = mydict.get(char, 0) + 1
```

However, there exists a better method: [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(int)
for char in string:
    mydict[char] += 1
```

or [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
mydict = Counter(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do aceess `char` for the first time, `dict.get(char)` returns `None`, not `0`. This should solve:

```
mydict[char] = (mydict.get(char) if char in mydict else 0) + 1
```

Comment: Oh, @tim-pietzcker answer is better.